# Выходит табличка при обновлении страницы о подтверждении повторной отправки

Tags: php

У меня на сайте есть две страницы:

index.php

```
<? 
include ('php/function.php');
include ('php/header.php');
include ('php/page1.php');
include ('php/page2.php');
include ('php/page3.php');
include ('php/page4.php');
include ('php/page5.php'); 
?>
```

и administrator.php (личный кабинет администратора):

```
<?   if(($_POST['named']='Мое_имя') and ($_POST['passworded']='Мой_пароль')){

    include ('php/databaseedit.php');
    include ('php/edit.php');
    // header('location: administrator.php]);

} else {
    echo "Для входа на эту страницу необходимо ввести имя/пароль.";
}
?>
```

В части header.php, который лежит в index.php есть форма:

```
<form method="POST" action="administrator" id="administrator">
                <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="named" class="adminname" id="imput" placeholder="Имя" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
                <input maxlength="30" type="password" name="passworded" id='ikput' class="adminpassword" placeholder="Пароль" autocomplete="off"  value=""/>
                <div id="error" class="error">Имя или пароль неверны</div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" class="enter" name="send" id="enter" value="Войти" id="enter"/>   
                    <!-- <a href="administrator.php" class="enter" name="enter" id="enter" value="Войти" id="enter">Войти</a> -->
                    <input type="submit" class="close" value="Закрыть"/>
                </div> 
</form>
```

При вводе данных я отправляюсь в файл administrator.php. 
И тут возникает проблема. При обновлении страницы (при нажатии F5) выходит табличка:"На странице, которую вы ищете, использовалась введенная вами информация. При возврате на эту страницу может потребоваться повторить выполненные ранее действия. Продолжить?" Я понимаю, что в administrator.php после подключения частей страницы нужно прописать что-то вроде header, но в этом случае вообще ничего не выходит. Возможно, я неправильно это делаю. Не подскажете, в чем ошибка?